# How to set smtp configuration on run time

Tags: playframework

Plz suggest another way to set "mail.smtp.user" and "#mail.smtp.pass" except app.conf file.

Because we want to use multiple smtp accounts for sending multiple mail in single application.

So is there any way to authenticate smtp server at runtime like in java

```
 new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@abc.com","abc");             
            }}
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple SMTP accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible in a clean way. You can call [`Mail.getSession()`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/Mail.java#L94) and then `Mail.session = Session.getInstance(session.getProperties(), new SMTPAuthenticator(user, password));`
However this **is not threadsafe**. So I would recommend to use a different mail-library which are easy to use too and give you more flexibility. Another solution is to take the code from Mail.java and create a MultiMail.java which has instances for different keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the property at runtime?

```
System.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "admin");
```